# React Native app crashes at start without error message

Tags: react-native, expo

I've developped an app using Expo and as when the app loads, it crashes from the Android simulator or a real Android phone.

If I don't add any `console.log` there are no error showing up in the terminal.

Whenever I add some debug logs, I see some logs printed for each debug line located in my `Home.js` (DEBUG 10 and 12), but not related to the crash itself. See below:

Android Bundling complete 56977ms

```
 LOG  DEBUG 0
 LOG  DEBUG 5
 LOG  DEBUG 4
 LOG  DEBUG 3
 LOG  DEBUG 2
 LOG  DEBUG 1
 WARN  DEBUG 12
Home@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:185649:26
StaticContainer@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:127642:17
EnsureSingleNavigator@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:124499:24
SceneView@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:127552:22
RCTView
View
RCTView
View
RCTView
View
CardSheet@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:162361:23
RCTView
View
AnimatedComponent@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:62920:38
AnimatedComponentWrapper
PanGestureHandler@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:153561:38
PanGestureHandler@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:160888:34
RCTView
View
AnimatedComponent@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:62920:38
AnimatedComponentWrapper
RCTView
View
Card@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:161860:36
CardContainer@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:162412:34
RNSScreen
AnimatedComponent@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:62920:38
AnimatedComponentWrapper
MaybeFreeze@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:133081:23
Screen@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:133117:36
MaybeScreen@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:161796:24
RNSScreenContainer
ScreenContainer@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:133222:31
MaybeScreenContainer@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:161785:23
RCTView
View
Background@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:129384:21
CardStack@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:161399:36
RCTView
View
SafeAreaProviderCompat@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:130603:25
RNGestureHandlerRootView
GestureHandlerRootView
StackView@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:160491:36
PreventRemoveProvider@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:126353:25
NavigationContent@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:127362:22
http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:127374:27
StackNavigator@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:160391:18
HomeStackScreen@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:102699:22
StaticContainer@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:127642:17
EnsureSingleNavigator@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:124499:24
SceneView@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:127552:22
RCTView
View
RCTView
View
Background@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:129384:21
Screen@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:130647:71
RNSScreen
AnimatedComponent@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:62920:38
AnimatedComponentWrapper
MaybeFreeze@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:133081:23
Screen@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:133117:36
MaybeScreen@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:132951:24
RNSScreenContainer
ScreenContainer@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:133222:31
MaybeScreenContainer@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:132939:23
RCTView
View
SafeAreaProviderCompat@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:130603:25
BottomTabView@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:129084:30
PreventRemoveProvider@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:126353:25
NavigationContent@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:127362:22
http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:127374:27
BottomTabNavigator@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:122487:18
BottomTabsScreen@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:102753:42
StaticContainer@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:127642:17
EnsureSingleNavigator@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:124499:24
SceneView@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:127552:22
RCTView
View
RCTView
View
Background@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:129384:21
Screen@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:130647:71
RNSScreen
AnimatedComponent@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:62920:38
AnimatedComponentWrapper
MaybeFreeze@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:133081:23
Screen@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:133117:36
MaybeScreen@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:158731:24
RNSScreenContainer
ScreenContainer@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:133222:31
MaybeScreenContainer@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:158719:23
RCTView
View
RCTView
View
AnimatedComponent(View)@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:150529:38
RCTView
View
AnimatedComponent(View)@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:150529:38
PanGestureHandler@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:153561:38
Drawer@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:159252:26
DrawerViewBase@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:133841:22
RNGestureHandlerRootView
GestureHandlerRootView
RCTView
View
SafeAreaProviderCompat@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:130603:25
DrawerView@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:134048:27
PreventRemoveProvider@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:126353:25
NavigationContent@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:127362:22
http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:127374:27
DrawerNavigator@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:133734:18
AppSideDrawerScreen
StaticContainer@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:127642:17
EnsureSingleNavigator@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:124499:24
SceneView@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:127552:22
RCTView
View
RCTView
View
RCTView
View
CardSheet@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:162361:23
RCTView
View
AnimatedComponent@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:62920:38
AnimatedComponentWrapper
PanGestureHandler@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:153561:38
PanGestureHandler@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:160888:34
RCTView
View
AnimatedComponent@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:62920:38
AnimatedComponentWrapper
RCTView
View
Card@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:161860:36
CardContainer@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:162412:34
RNSScreen
AnimatedComponent@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:62920:38
AnimatedComponentWrapper
MaybeFreeze@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:133081:23
Screen@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:133117:36
MaybeScreen@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:161796:24
RNSScreenContainer
ScreenContainer@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:133222:31
MaybeScreenContainer@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:161785:23
RCTView
View
Background@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:129384:21
CardStack@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:161399:36
RNCSafeAreaProvider
SafeAreaProvider@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:129772:24
SafeAreaProviderCompat@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:130603:25
RNGestureHandlerRootView
GestureHandlerRootView
StackView@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:160491:36
PreventRemoveProvider@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:126353:25
NavigationContent@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:127362:22
http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:127374:27
StackNavigator@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:160391:18
RootStackScreen@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:102827:50
EnsureSingleNavigator@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:124499:24
BaseNavigationContainer@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:123091:28
ThemeProvider@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:128537:21
NavigationContainerInner@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:128428:26
http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:102881:41
StorageContextProvider@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:166486:24
_default
ExpoRoot@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:102427:22
RCTView
View
RCTView
View
AppContainer@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:69668:36
main(RootComponent)@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:74773:28
 LOG  groups table created
 LOG  savedRuns table created
 WARN  DEBUG 11
Home@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:185649:26
StaticContainer@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:127642:17
EnsureSingleNavigator@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:124499:24
SceneView@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:127552:22
RCTView
View
RCTView
View
RCTView
View
CardSheet@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:162361:23
RCTView
View
AnimatedComponent@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:62920:38
AnimatedComponentWrapper
PanGestureHandler@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:153561:38
PanGestureHandler@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:160888:34
RCTView
View
AnimatedComponent@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:62920:38
AnimatedComponentWrapper
RCTView
View
Card@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:161860:36
CardContainer@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:162412:34
RNSScreen
AnimatedComponent@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:62920:38
AnimatedComponentWrapper
MaybeFreeze@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:133081:23
Screen@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:133117:36
MaybeScreen@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:161796:24
RNSScreenContainer
ScreenContainer@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:133222:31
MaybeScreenContainer@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:161785:23
RCTView
View
Background@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:129384:21
CardStack@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:161399:36
RCTView
View
SafeAreaProviderCompat@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:130603:25
RNGestureHandlerRootView
GestureHandlerRootView
StackView@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:160491:36
PreventRemoveProvider@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:126353:25
NavigationContent@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:127362:22
http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:127374:27
StackNavigator@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:160391:18
HomeStackScreen@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:102699:22
StaticContainer@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:127642:17
EnsureSingleNavigator@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:124499:24
SceneView@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:127552:22
RCTView
View
RCTView
View
Background@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:129384:21
Screen@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:130647:71
RNSScreen
AnimatedComponent@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:62920:38
AnimatedComponentWrapper
MaybeFreeze@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:133081:23
Screen@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:133117:36
MaybeScreen@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:132951:24
RNSScreenContainer
ScreenContainer@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:133222:31
MaybeScreenContainer@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:132939:23
RCTView
View
SafeAreaProviderCompat@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:130603:25
BottomTabView@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:129084:30
PreventRemoveProvider@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:126353:25
NavigationContent@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:127362:22
http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:127374:27
BottomTabNavigator@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:122487:18
BottomTabsScreen@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:102753:42
StaticContainer@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:127642:17
EnsureSingleNavigator@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:124499:24
SceneView@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:127552:22
RCTView
View
RCTView
View
Background@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:129384:21
Screen@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:130647:71
RNSScreen
AnimatedComponent@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:62920:38
AnimatedComponentWrapper
MaybeFreeze@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:133081:23
Screen@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:133117:36
MaybeScreen@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:158731:24
RNSScreenContainer
ScreenContainer@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:133222:31
MaybeScreenContainer@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:158719:23
RCTView
View
RCTView
View
AnimatedComponent(View)@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:150529:38
RCTView
View
AnimatedComponent(View)@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:150529:38
PanGestureHandler@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:153561:38
Drawer@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:159252:26
DrawerViewBase@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:133841:22
RNGestureHandlerRootView
GestureHandlerRootView
RCTView
View
SafeAreaProviderCompat@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:130603:25
DrawerView@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:134048:27
PreventRemoveProvider@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:126353:25
NavigationContent@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:127362:22
http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:127374:27
DrawerNavigator@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:133734:18
AppSideDrawerScreen
StaticContainer@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:127642:17
EnsureSingleNavigator@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:124499:24
SceneView@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:127552:22
RCTView
View
RCTView
View
RCTView
View
CardSheet@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:162361:23
RCTView
View
AnimatedComponent@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:62920:38
AnimatedComponentWrapper
PanGestureHandler@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:153561:38
PanGestureHandler@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:160888:34
RCTView
View
AnimatedComponent@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:62920:38
AnimatedComponentWrapper
RCTView
View
Card@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:161860:36
CardContainer@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:162412:34
RNSScreen
AnimatedComponent@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:62920:38
AnimatedComponentWrapper
MaybeFreeze@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:133081:23
Screen@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:133117:36
MaybeScreen@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:161796:24
RNSScreenContainer
ScreenContainer@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:133222:31
MaybeScreenContainer@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:161785:23
RCTView
View
Background@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:129384:21
CardStack@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:161399:36
RNCSafeAreaProvider
SafeAreaProvider@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:129772:24
SafeAreaProviderCompat@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:130603:25
RNGestureHandlerRootView
GestureHandlerRootView
StackView@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:160491:36
PreventRemoveProvider@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:126353:25
NavigationContent@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:127362:22
http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:127374:27
StackNavigator@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:160391:18
RootStackScreen@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:102827:50
EnsureSingleNavigator@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:124499:24
BaseNavigationContainer@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:123091:28
ThemeProvider@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:128537:21
NavigationContainerInner@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:128428:26
http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:102881:41
StorageContextProvider@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:166486:24
_default
ExpoRoot@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:102427:22
RCTView
View
RCTView
View
AppContainer@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:69668:36
main(RootComponent)@http://192.168.0.117:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:74773:28
 LOG  2022-10-22T12:28:21.887Z+0200
```

This has hapenned after upgrading from Expo SDK 40 to 46, I am trying to make my app work with the latest SDK.

I've been reading the Expo doc but I can't figure out how to troubleshoot further. I've tried to build the app and debug through Android Studio but that didn't work.
It seems the app can reach my Home.js screen but crashes directly after that.

Comment: Try upgrading react-native-reanimated to 2.10.0 or newer if you use it. I had the same issue with 2.9.1.

Comment: I'm struggling with latest version of react-native-navigated and Expo 46. It seems they are not compatible. Will update when it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated `react-native-reanimated` to 2.12.0 and it works fine now. I was able to troubleshoot remaining issue.

Note that as of today, `react-native-reanimated` 2.12.0 is not compatible with Expo 46, but I have found no issue so far; I only get a warning:

```
Some dependencies are incompatible with the installed expo version:
  react-native-reanimated@2.12.0 - expected version: ~2.9.1
```